# In GA Real Time it is showing me Product Details but not the product URL after configuring in tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager for when i configuring "Measuring Views of Product Details" In custom event when i configure event equals product detail

And in the website's source code (i.e. in datalayer push) I am using - `'event': 'ProductDetail'`

So in google analytics Real time when anyone visits my product page it shows me "Productdetails" but not the actual product url.

Can anyone tell me how to configure tag manager so I can see product url in real-time?

FYI - I have an e-shop with more than 10k products.

Comment: Can anyone please share your knowledge

Comment: Please, be more specific. How do you configure this? Some more info or screenshot of how your tag is configured. Basically, GA real time view will not show you Event urls be default. You need to pass it in Event Action or Event Label. To be more precise on what you need to change, I need to see how you've defined actual Event tracking.